# numkeypad not working on dell n5110 after installing 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell

I have a dell inspiron n5110 with ubuntu 13.04 fresh install.before when i was using 11.10 / 12.04 numkeypad used to work .now it works only at the log in where i type password. after the login it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Check the NumLock key, is it activated?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking System Settings/Universal Access/Pointing and Clicking to see if Mouse Keys have been turned on. Specifically, make sure that "Control the pointer using the keypad" is turned off.